# Set feature styles dynamically in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to make a leaflet layer that will listen to a slider bar and change the colour of all its features based on if a property of each feature meets a certain criterion.

I begin by getting the event:

```
$( "#time-slider-bar" ).on("slidechange", function() {
```

and then I try to change the style on each feature like so:

```
        thresholdLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {

            var year = $("#time-slider-bar").slider("option", "value");

            console.log("_yr"+year);
            console.log(layer.feature.properties["_yr"+year]);

            return layer.setStyle(function(layer) {

                console.log("does not print");

                if (layer.feature.properties["_yr"+year] > 100) {
                    return {
                        fillColor: "#ff0000",
                        fillOpacity: 1
                    };
                } else {
                    return {
                        fillOpacity: 0
                    };
                }
            })
        })
```

But then nothing happens.  The `console.log("does not print");` statement does just that - doesn't print.  For some reason, `layer.setStyle` is not executing.  Am I not using this function correctly? I am following a previous example where I changed an icon on a different layer:

```
        markerLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            return layer.setIcon(L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'svg/' + $("#time-slider-bar").slider("option", "value") + '/' + layer.feature.properties.name + '.svg'
            }))
        });
```

Which works just fine.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this: call 'layer.setStyle' (don't return it), then use another function to build the options object, feeding it the 'year' variable...

Here is a JS Bin with an example (it listens for a button-click): 
https://jsbin.com/hobohah/2/edit?html,js,console,output

And here I tried to write out the code using your variable names and styling options:

```
$( "#time-slider-bar" ).on("slidechange", function() {

      var year = $("#time-slider-bar").slider("option", "value");

      thresholdLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {

          // don't return layer.setStyle-- just call it. 
          // the setStyle method expects an object. 
          // we can use another function to build and return that object, if we feed it the 'year' value. 

          layer.setStyle(getStyle(year));
      }
}

function getStyle(y){
    if (y > 100) {return {fillColor: "#ff0000", fillOpacity: 1}}
    else {return {fillOpacity: 0}}
}
```